# How to enable key down event if it's already disabled in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code where I am disabling ENTER button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if ((event.keyCode == 13) && ($('#btnsubmit').disabled)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In some cases I want to enable it and want the ENTER key to work as expected. Could someone help me out in fixing this?

Comment: You can use jQuery's `on` and `off` to enable and disable event

Comment: Tushar, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: api.jquery.com/on  http://api.jquery.com/off/ Read these

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

use the flag approach:

```js
var enterDisabled = true;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).keydown(function(event) {
    // check if enterDisabled flag is on and disable enter
    if (enterDisabled && (event.keyCode == 13) && ($('#btnsubmit').prop('disabled'))) {
      alert("enter is disabled");
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("#enterToggler").click(function() {
    enterDisabled = !enterDisabled;
    $("#status").text(enterDisabled);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="submit" disabled="disabled" />
<button id="enterToggler">Toggle Enter</button>
<br/>Enter Disabled: <span id="status">true</span>
```

simply set the flat to false when you need the enter to work...

Comment: That is a nice idea. But I guess, it will work after page reloading. Will it work if we have to toggle without page reloading?

Comment: @SPradhan you can declare `enterDisabled` as true by default, so enter will always be disabled. and then you can toggle it to `true`/`false` whenever and wherever you want, just remember to declare the flag in the global scope (outside of all functions) so that you can access it from anywhere in the script.

Comment: While disabling ENTER, it can be checked against flag variable. But, Don't I have to write scripts to enable it from some other method exclusively? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SPradhan all you need to do is set the flag to false. the Enter key is not being really **'disabled'**, what happens is that on every key down you prevent default action, and return false (both do the same in fact you only need one of them). this keydown handler runs on **EVERY** key down, so once the flag is off, the handler will not return false and the enter will work normally.